# how to css format for devexpress gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I am trying to learn devexpress gridview. I setup everything and works fine but there is a styling problem.

In old days, when u drag and drop a gridview from the visual studio's toolbar, it used to look perfect but the gridview from devexpress doesnt look nice. something is wrong with this.

here is the image...

[image]

it seems like the grid is in a div block and there is a margin at the right and top. I am using a trial version of devexpress. Do u think it is because of the trial or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress controls allow for a lot of customization. You can do that via the "Run Designer" button, or via events like "CustomDrawColumnHeader", "CustomDrawCell" etc. You can also contact them, they have a great Support Team. I've been using them for a while and the results I'm getting are way better of the standard Visual Studio controls.